# Toggling many div id

Tags: jquery, html

I have many div to hide/show when the user clicks the toggle button. My toggle button is working but is there a shorter way to write the codes? It should be, when `lblBtn1` is clicked only the `dtxt1` will slide, and if `lblBtn2` is clicked it will show the `dtxt2`.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#lblBtn1").click(function(){
      $("#dtxt1").slideToggle();
      });
      $("#lblBtn2").click(function(){
      $("#dtxt2").slideToggle();
      });
   });
```

**html**

```
<lbl id="lblBtn1">&#43;</lbl>Menu1 
    <div id="dtxt1">ASDFGH</div>

<lbl id="lblBtn2">&#43;</lbl>Menu2 
    <div id="dtxt2">QWERTY</div>
```

Comment: adding a same named class both can select only the clicked div $(".className")

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
// Shorter $(document).ready
$(function () {
    // Use attribute selector for both of your #id because they are like each other..
    $("[id^=lblBtn]").click(function () { // or $("#lblBtn1, #lblBtn2").click(function () { 
        // Use next function to find next div to slideToggle because they are next to each other (siblings)
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use id start with selector or tagname selector to target all label element along `$(this).next()` to target desired div elements:

```
$("[id^=lblBtn]").click(function(){//or $("lbl").click(function(){
   $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

**[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvsbv9vx/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^="lblBtn"]').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

This will work for all the labels

Or try click event on `<lbl>` tags

Answer (score 0):

This will target the desired #dtxt even if it is not directly next to #lblBtn

```js
$('[id^=lblBtn]').click(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('id').replace('lblBtn', '');
    $('[id=dtxt' + num + ']').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<lbl id="lblBtn1">&#43;</lbl>Menu1 
    <div id="dtxt1">ASDFGH</div>

<lbl id="lblBtn2">&#43;</lbl>Menu2 
    <div id="dtxt2">QWERTY</div>
```