# Toggle MANY divs onclick in Vue without pre-declaring the variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have many elements (around 30) to toggle (hide/show) on click. I use the v-show directive, but I need to declare all the variables name beforehand. If I don't declare them, the v-show doesn't work. This is not practical because every time the elements change I would have to change them in the template and in the list.

Is there a way to achieve this in Vue without pre-declaring the variables, or I'll have to do something like in this answer in pure JavaScript [Toggling many div id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27615617/toggling-many-div-id) ?

Comment: Do all these divs have to depend on different variables? Can it be one variable only?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but could you build a component for the "divs" and then loop through the array of 30 elements and manage the toggle from this new component? In this new component, which handle an individual element, you can manage the click function and hide/show the element using perhaps the display property on he element.

Comment: The divs depend on different variables. Answer of Tim is something I tried to implement, only with the <template v-for..> instead of the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this if you generate the variables programatically

```
data() {
 return {
  items: [...Array(30).keys()].map(i => ({ id: i, isActive: true }))
 };
}
```

This will generate an object with 30 entries that have an `id` and a flag regarding active status.

You can now `v-for` over them and handle the click based on the `id`

```
<div
  v-for="item in items"
  :key="item.index"
  v-show="item.isActive"
  @click="handleClick(item)"
>{{item.id}}</div>
```

And finally the `handleClick` method

```
methods: {
 handleClick(item) {
  item.isActive = false;
 }
},
```

A working example can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-almeida-ypdwk?file=/src/App.vue:346-422)

Answer (score -1):

if you have to show 30 divs simultaneously you can do this.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a @click="!isActive">Toggle to Show Divs</a> <-- At click, isActive = !isActive -->
        <div id="1" v-if="isActive"></div> <!-- Show when isActive = true -->
        <div id="2" v-if="isActive"></div> 
        <div id="3" v-if="isActive"></div> 
        <div id="4" v-if="isActive"></div> 
        <div id="5" v-if="isActive"></div> 
        <div id="6" v-if="isActive"></div> 
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                isActive: false
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

The only variable will be `isActive`

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work since all the divs depend on different variables.

Comment: The question is about individual toggle for each element without declaring variables. Not all at once.